# SQL Server 2014 takes off leading zeroes when making Excel file. . . but.

Tags: sql-server, excel

This `sp_send_dbmail` script works in one of our processes. It attaches an Excel file filled with whatever the query is. It knows to do this because of the extension on the file's name (.xls).

However, it changes a `varchar(50)` field into a number field, and removes the leading zeroes. This is a known annoyance dealt with in a million ways that won't work for my process.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = @profileName
   ,@recipients = @emailRecipientList
   ,@subject = @subject
   ,@importance = @importance
   ,@body = @emailMsg
   ,@body_format = 'html'
   ,@query = @QuerySQL
   ,@execute_query_database = @QueryDB
   ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
   ,@query_attachment_filename = @QueryExcelFileName
   ,@query_result_header = 1
   ,@query_result_width = @QueryWidth
   ,@query_result_separator = @QuerySep
   ,@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Examples of problem below: this simple query changes the StringNumber column from varchar to number in Excel, and removes the zeroes.

```
SELECT [RowID],[Verbage], StringNumber FROM [dbo].[tblTestStringNumber]
```

In SQL Server (desired format):

[image: View of table in SQL Server]

After in Excel (leading zeroes missing):

[image: Excel results with no leading zeroes]

Now, there might be a way. I only say this because in SQL Server 2016 results pane, if you right click in upper left hand corner, it gives the option of "Open in Excel"

[image: Right Click to Open in Excel]

And. . . . drum roll . . . the dataset opens in Excel and the leading zeroes are still there!

[image]

Comment: I can tell you that if an Excell cell is a number, then you cannot have leading 0s in it.

Comment: The first is changing anything that looks like numbers to number and the second it is being imported as a text string as that is what the column is in sql.  To fix the first simply format the offending column to `000000` and it will display as you want.

Comment: David: Got that, thank you. SQl Server has varchar, Excel says number and takes off zeroes.

Comment: Scott: Don't need number format. Excel say I do, takes off zeroes. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this is not an excel file it's a text file. Save the attachment and open in notepad and you'll discover this. So the challenge is to get Excel to recognise a CSV properly. What is your `@querysep` set to? That's a very handy right click export to excel trick but I can't find it in my SSMS? Anyway I think your best bet is to experiment with text files and see which particular format works. Possibly none! If this is absolutely critical you could cook up an SSIS package to export as Excel and email it off, although it has its own problems.

Comment: Nick, I see the right-click "Open in Excel" using SSMS 2016. Could you be using an earlier version? Just saying, somewhere in SQL Server it got it right, but is not available through code, sql, whatever. I think we will have to automate an Excel file from an SSRS button in report header to create, format cells, and loop through and fill. How often have we done that using MS Access and Excel? This functionality exists. We thought we could get db_sendmail to do it, but it removes the zeroes or adds a tick.

Answer (score 1):

If you start a number with a single quote (') in Excel, it will interpret it as a string, so a common solution is to change the query to add one in:

```
SELECT [RowID]
    ,[Verbage]
    , StringNumber = '''' + [StringNumber] 
FROM [dbo].[tblTestStringNumber]
```

And Excel will usually not display the single quote because it knows that it's a way to cast to type string.

Comment: Russell: Been there done that. It doesn't show the single quote but it takes off the leading zeroes anyway.  If I concate single quotes like this: Concat('''''''', [StringNumber]) As StringNumber it shows leading zeroes AND single tick. Client can't have that (picky picky).

Comment: That is a sticky wicket. I've also seen people add a space character at the front, but then you have, well, a space character at the front. Another solution is to create an SSRS report and have a subscription generate it into an Excel file. That gives you more control over formatting and Excel will usually play nice.

Comment: empty space or quote quote in front doesn't work. Attempt at using db_sendmail was to solve the fact that the SSRS report opens nice, shows dataset, but when clicking on the little "export as Excel" it creates a cludgy excel file with empty rows, clunky header, unacceptable to any automation past just looking at it. Hence some other way to create the Excel file that keeps leading zeroes. The client is picky, boo hoo. Nothing wrong with that. Moderators on SO are pickier than any client I have.

Comment: Gotcha. I do have a lot of experience creating reports that export nicely into Excel, so feel free to reach out if it comes to that.

Answer (score 1):

@JustJohn I think it will work fine:

```
SELECT [RowID]
    ,[Verbage]
    ,  '="' + [StringNumber]+ '"' StringNumber
FROM [dbo].[tblTestStringNumber]
```